# To set Audio Format using AudioRecorder

Tags: android, android-emulator, audio-recording, android-mediaplayer

I am Running Android SDK, 2.2 and set Samsung Galaxy Tab as target, using following code to create Audio Recorder Object,

```
private static final int AUDIO_BUFFER_SAMPLEREAD_SIZE = 8000;
public int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO; 
public int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT;
```

Creating Audio Recorder Object,

```
bufferbytesize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplingRate,channelConfiguration,audioEncoding);
```

But i am always getting bufferbytesize is -2, which means something wrong with the input format, which i have provided, 
Does that mean, on Android Emulator doesn't support 8000 Sampling rate with 8 bit PCM data, or Are there any workaround to get rid out it,